# How to best serve PHP and Python (single file) from one NGINX?

Tags: nginx, php, python

We have developed a Java RIA Fat Client that is accompanied by some very small PHP scripts on an NGINX webserver. I very much like the fact that one PHP file is one HTTP endpoint, no routing / front controller pattern etc.

Now, we feel that PHP is poisoning our minds, and we want to be able to create these little scripts in Python as well. I would like to keep the existing PHP scripts.

What's the best way to enable NGINX to also serve single file Python apps?

(Nothing is off the table. Should I switch to Apache / mod_python and mod_php? Should I try uWSGI?)

Comment: You could absolutely just use uWSGI for the python side (with fastcgi + fpm for the PHP side)

Comment: No, you really should not use `mod_python` or `mod_php`.

Comment: @JoshuaDeWald, so it's only a misunderstanding of mine - I could use any WSGI application server for single small python scripts as well? The examples always looked like app servers who would run continously and listen for connections

Comment: Well if you have an actual http server process, you can just use a `proxy_pass` and don't need to do anything specific with WSGI